# Origin of “lacksadaisical” (misspelled and mispronounced for “lackadaisical”)

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, eggcorn

I was astonished to learn that the word *lacksadaisical* or *laxadaisical* is both misspelled and mispronounced. It is still commonly used in Southern Africa (with the same meaning), whereas it is rare to hear the correct *lackadaisical* in mainstream use.

Does anyone have insight into the origin of *lacksadaisical*?

Comment: Probably it got started when somebody who was not familiar with the word misheard it and then tried to use it with other people who were not familiar with it either. And when trying to make sense of the word, associated with the word lax.

Comment: @Jim: I couldn't find them in dictionaries(OED, NOAD, etc.). Are they really words?

Comment: @Noah As the OP notes, they are common misspellings and mispronunciations of [lackadaisical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lackadaisical). You won't find an erroneous version in the dictionary except perhaps to indicate that it is a common typo.

Comment: If we are to take the question as presented, Jim's comment above is the only answer given so far.  The rep-earning answers below explain *lackadaisical*, which doesn't address the question at all.  (Whether it is a fair question to ask is another matter.)

Comment: @JohnY: I like Jim's theory, too – especially the part about an association with the word _lax_ – but it's going to be rather hard to find the "origin" of a common mispronunciation. (If that's really the question here, I don't want to be oopsydaisical; I'll just cast a "not constructive" vote instead.)

Comment: I have never heard anything *but* "lackadaisical".  Odd.

Comment: -1 question shows no research effort. @JohnY is right -- answers so far don't address the variant word except to let us know that Barrie England is not surprised. I am not ready to close this question though: maybe there's an interesting story somewhere in this about South African pronunciation or orthography.

Comment: I don't know the origins/etymology but we definitely say lacksadaisical in the north of England!

Comment: [There was also a reading teacher who, when using the word lackadaisical in her presentations before class, added on her own authority an extra **s**, producing **lacksadaisical**; she invariably added an extra syllable to **mischievous, mischievious**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22teacher+who%2C+when+using+the+word+lackadaisical%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). I think the "South Africa"  connotation is just a red herring.

Comment: @user83178, same here south-east England.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/) spells it as *lackadaisical* and defines it as

> Resembling one who is given to crying 'Lackaday!'; full of vapid
>   feeling or sentiment; affectedly languishing. Said of persons, their
>   behaviour, manners, and utterances.

The first recorded use is in 1768. It is derived from *lackadaisy* (first recorded in 1748), which in turn comes from *lack-a-day*, a version of *alack the day!* or *alack-a-day!*, originally used to mean ‘Shame or reproach to the day! Woe worth the day!’ but in later usage an expression of  surprise (same source).

Variant spellings and pronunciations in South Africa or elsewhere don't surprise me, given the word's chequered history.

Comment: Thanks Barrie - I guess this is lost in the mists of time. I will take great pleasure in correcting my colleagues (or boss :) next time I hear it.

Answer (score -1):

The Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English mentions the following meaning and origin.

Meaning:

> lack‧​a‧​dai‧​si‧​cal /ˌ​lækəˈdeɪzɪkəl◂/ 
>   not showing enough interest in something or not putting enough effort into it:

Origin:

> lackadaisical
>   Date: 1700–1800
>   Origin: lackaday expression of sadness (17–19 centuries), from alack the day

Pay attention to the correct spelling and pronunciation.

Comment: Am fully aware of the correct spelling and meaning, as my OP suggests, however the question revolves around the origin of the mispronunciation which has become widespread in Southern Africa.